# Median with groupby and frequency

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby, median

Suppose I have this dataframe called 'market'

```
market = pd.DataFrame({'product': ['milk', 'milk', 'milk', 'bread', 'bread'], 
                   'frequency': [4,2,6,3,5],
                  'price_each': [3,4,5,10,8]})
market
```

This will be

```
product frequency price_each
milk    4         3
milk    2         4
milk    6         5
bread   3         10
bread   5         8
```

How to calculate this median properly by groupby product and it use frequency?

What I have done (but get wrong result)

```
market.groupby('product')['price_each'].median()
```

The real and expected result is

```
product   median of price each
milk      4.5       
bread     8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `numpy.repeat` and `numpy.median`:

```
new_df = market.groupby('product').apply(lambda x: np.median(np.repeat(x['price_each'], x['frequency'])))
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
product
bread    8.0
milk     4.5
dtype: float64
```